# Setting up vs code for Java Gradle Build Error

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I set up `jdt.ls.java.home` propertie in settings and i chagned my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable propertly, but my Gradle is throwing out this error:[Gradle Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21S3q.png)
There is also some sort of that error:
[secound error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtDpS.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a different java home to Gradle via `User setting` `java.import.gradle.java.home`.

`jdt.ls.java.home` is used to launch the Java Language Server, and the extension had embedded a JRE to start the Java Language Server. So it doesn't matter, you can remove it.

And what's the value of `C:\Programe Files\Eclipse Adoptiu..`? please make sure it's an executable java path.